# Blutooth keyboard does not work after long suspend

Tags: keyboard, suspend, bluetooth, logitech

Logitech K380 does not work after wake up. Toggling any bluetooth/device turn on/off buttons still does not make it work. The only solution I found is to reboot the Ubuntu. Although if the laptop is only suspended for a short time before waking up it will work, I guess it is due to device sleep for saving power.

Logitech support actually have [an article](http://support.logitech.com/en_us/article/Bluetooth-device-doesn-t-work-after-computer-wakes-from-sleep-mode?product=a0qi0000008uJndAAE) for this problem. But it addresses only Windows and Mac.

Comment: Same here on Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 with the Logitech K380.

Comment: I have been fighting the same issue. Love the keyboard, but just cannot make it work consistently with ubuntu.The only joy I have it switch off the bluetooth option that bluetooth can be switched off - then turn it on again and I can often use the keyboard. Otherwise I'm forced to reboot.